CATIA V5 - Automating the exporting of mesh data from an Analysis file using VBA
I am developing a process in CATIA v5 where I would like to automate the meshing of a part and then - and this is the part I'm stuck on - I would like to automatically export the data to a txt file. I am trying to use the function ExportData(), but I am getting a type mismatch error. Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error, Description: Type mismatch: 'ExportData'.
Here is the section of my code that is important:
    Dim FileSys as FileSystem
    Dim FoldObj as Folder
    Dim FileName as CATBSTR
    Dim FileExt as CATBSTR

    Set FileSys = CATIA.FileSystem
    Set FoldObj = FileSys.GetFolder("C:\Users\username\Documents\configs\")
    
    FileName = "Config_"

    FileExt = "txt"

    Call ExportData(FoldObj,FileName,FileExt)

    boolParam1.Value = FileSys.FolderExists("C:\Users\username\Documents\configs\") 

The parameter that I have defined as boolParam1 is indeed changing to True, so the folder does in fact exist. I am struggling to see where a type mismatch could possibly be coming from.
Just to be absolutely clear, I am attempting to automate the "Export Mesh" command in the Advanced Meshing Tools workbench, so if there is a different function I should be using please let me know. Also, I am automating it because eventually it will loop through multiple rows of a design table and mesh then save each design. We already have code to automate the meshing, it's the automated exporting that is new.

I guess the ExportData belongs to the AnalysisImage  object. Have you defined/created one in the AnalysisDocument?

@Shrotter I see. It appears there are no pre-written functions for AnalysisDocuments. So I will likely have to write the Export Mesh command from scratch in VBA for what I want to accomplish?

You may look onto the example CAAAniPostProExportData.catvbs in the documentation. This may also work in the Advanced Meshing Tools
